# Samsung Galaxy Tablet E, Model SM-T377W Unable to Factory Reset

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, tablet, partitions

I'm able to get to the menu Android Recovery when I select Wipe data/ factory reset but**** the yes or no option does not appear, and tablet reverts back to lock screen. Then I tried to clear cache (delete) and the yes no option was present so I cleared cache and again tried to factory reset/wipe data again Yes / No option failed to appear.  Bottom of screen says         No support Single SKU,        E: ensure_path_unmounted Failed tounmount/ easy (DeviceFailed to find) misc. Partitions,   and back to lock screen.
Any ideas or answers would be greatly appreciated- thanks, Tamara

Comment: Welcome Tamara!  Can you edit your question to make it easier to read?  Thanks!